# Retrieve data from a json file using angular js

Tags: angularjs

Using Angular js, I want to retrieve data from a json file which is at a remote location. Here's my code. Please tell me what am I missing as I am unable to get the data.

**My View**

```
<body ng-controller='companyController as comctrl'>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="com in comctrl.companies" ng-bind="com.name"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

**My Controller**

```
app.controller('companyController', ['$http',
    function($http) 
    {
        this.companies = [];
        $http
            .get('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/28961916/companies.json')
            .success(function(data)
            {
                this.companies=data;
            });
    }
]);
```

**JSON File**

```
{
    businesses: [
    {
        id: 3184,
        name: "Nintoreion Soft Pvt Ltd",
        status: 'Private',
        turnover: 500,
        domain: 'Software Technology'
    },
    {
        id: 3489,
        name: "Prandeious Solutions",
        status: 'Public',
        turnover: 300,
        domain: 'Software Technology',
    },
    // so on
]}
```

Comment: what is the error that u get?

Comment: Try making an app.factory('businessFactory', function() { return { businesses: [...] };})

Then inject it into your controller with app.controller('companyController', function(businessFactory){...});

Answer (score 0):

`this` doesn't refer to the controller in the callback. Try...

```
app.controller('companyController',['$http',function($http){
    var self = this;
    this.companies=[];
    $http.get('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/28961916/companies.json').success(function(data){
        self.companies = data;
    });
}]);
```

The JSON is also invalid (properties need to be in double quotes). Use something like http://jsonlint.com/ to validate it.

Comment: Yes indeed the JSON is invalid. Thanks for pointing out this and for sharing the the url to validate json. How should I proceed now, I don't have any other remote json file.

Comment: If you just want a remote JSON api for the sake of testing, you can use [Open Weather Map](http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London)

Answer (score 0):

I would go with

```
app.controller('companyController', ['$scope', '$http',
    function($scope, $http) 
    {
        $scope.companies = [];
        $http
            .get('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/28961916/companies.json')
            .success(function(data) 
            {
                $scope.companies = data;
            });
    }
]);
```

Use `$scope` instead of `this`.

Comment: Thanks. I used $scope. The error which I get now is - Cannot read property 'get' of undefined. I think the problem is with json. is it?

Comment: Note that the above code didn't include the $scope as a dependency as with $http.

Comment: @MarcusNielsen, thanks for remaining me! I'll fix the code right away

Comment: @user3854295, try including the `$scope` and let me know how it works out

Comment: After including $scope I am getting this error- SyntaxError: Unexpected token b
    at Object.parse (native)
    at Wb (file:///E:/study/handsOn/angular.min.js:14:208)
    at Td.e.defaults.transformResponse (file:///E:/study/handsOn/angular.min.js:67:454)
    at file:///E:/study/handsOn/angular.min.js:67:215
    at Array.forEach (native)

Comment: I think the problem is your API's formatting of the JSON? How does your API create the .json file?